# Erro de Execução 424 - Importar múltiplos arquivos XML no VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, xml, vba

Sou completamente novo em *vba* e estou tendo um problema no meu código.

Estou precisando extrair dados de algumas tags de vários arquivos *XML*. Quando executo o código ou realizo o debub, aparece o erro de *424* "O objeto é obrigatório" na linha `XML.Filename = fd.SelectedItems(i)`.

Aqui está o código:

```
Private Sub CommandButtonImport_Click()
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fd
        .Filters.Clear
        .Title = "Select Multiple XML Files"
        .Filters.Add "XML File", "*.xml", 1
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        
    If .Show = True Then
        Dim xdoc As Object
        Set xdoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
        xdoc.async = False: xdoc.validateOnParse = False
        row_number = 1
        For i = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
            XML.Filename = fd.SelectedItems(i)
            xdoc.Load (XML.Filename)
            Set Products = xdoc.DocumentElement
            For Each Product In Products.ChildNodes
                Application.Range("ProductsRange").Cells(row_number, 1).Value = Product.ChildNodes(0).Text
                Application.Range("ProductsRange").Cells(row_number, 2).Value = Product.ChildNodes(1).Text
                Application.Range("ProductsRange").Cells(row_number, 3).Value = Product.ChildNodes(2).Text
                Application.Range("ProductsRange").Cells(row_number, 4).Value = Product.ChildNodes(3).Text
                Application.Range("ProductsRange").Cells(row_number, 5).Value = Product.ChildNodes(4).Text
                Application.Range("ProductsRange").Cells(row_number, 6).Value = Product.ChildNodes(5).Text
                Application.Range("ProductsRange").Cells(row_number, 7).Value = Product.ChildNodes(6).Text
                row_number = 1 = row_number + 1
            
            Next Product
                        
        Next i
    
    End If
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Salve, meu caro!

Eu creio que o erro aconteceu porque a variável `XML` não foi definida. Como XML é `Nothing`, não tem propriedades (no seu caso, o `FileName` que você tentou atribuir). "O objeto é obrigatório" para ver se há essa propriedade e atribuí-la.

Você pode usar dois métodos para carregar o XML: `Load` e `LoadXML`. Ambos recebem como parâmetro strings. No caso do `Load`, a string deve conter o caminho do arquivo; no caso do `LoadXML`, a string deve conter o próprio texto do XML.

Sua opção foi usar o `Load` com o caminho do arquivo, então basta remover a referência à variável XML, que não existe, e passar a string com o caminho do arquivo direto para o `xdoc.Load`:

```
    For i = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
        ' XML.Filename = fd.SelectedItems(i)
        xdoc.Load fd.SelectedItems(i)
        ' Se eu entendi corretamente, isso aqui é o caminho do arquivo. Se for
        ' só o nome do arquivo, dê um jeito de adicionar o caminho, algo como
        ' xdoc.Load strCaminho & "\" & fd.SelectedItems(i)
```

Por fim, só pra explicar outro possível erro: `xdoc.Load (XML.Filename)` provavelmente resultará em erro. No VB, ao passar parâmetros, os parênteses só são utilizados quando há alguma atribuição de valor envolvida. Se na linha você estiver apenas chamando uma função ou método sem atribuir valor, não deve usar parênteses. Isso também acontece com `Functions` e `Subs`.
Por exemplo, digamos que você tem uma função que faz certas modificações na tela, sem retornar valores, e vai fazer a chamada dela. Como não há atribuição de valores, você não deve usar parênteses para passar os parâmetros (`MeuSubAjustaTela strCorDoTema`). Mas se a função retornar um valor e você quiser atribuir esse valor a uma variável (ou mesmo passar esse valor como parâmetro em outra função/método), aí deveria usar parênteses (`strCaminhoValidado = MinhaFunctionValidadora (strArquivo)`).